# how to get products for an attribute - magento

Tags: magento-1.7, dropdown-attribute, query

I have created a attribute fresh arrival with two values yes or no in dropdown and I am creating a block which is reading from a phtml file. How can I show all products which have fresh arrival set as yes in phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
(Assume your attribute code is `fresh_arrival`)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           ->addAttributeToFilter(fresh_arrival, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many products use the fresh arrival attribute, selecting them via SQL may be a better idea:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$connection_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity';
$catalog = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
foreach ($catalog as $product){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE value = ? AND entity_id = ? AND attribute_id = ?';
    $fresh_arrivals = $connection->fetchAll($sql, array(1, $product['entity_id'], attribute_id));
    foreach ($fresh_arrivals as $fresh_arrival){
        /*Make your changes here
         * 
         * i.e
         * 
         * $sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET attribute_value = ? WHERE entity_id = ? AND attribute_id = ?'
         * $connection_write->query($sql, array(attribute_value, $product['entity_id'], attribute_id));
         * 
         * */
    }
}
```

Note that you can figure out what your attribute ID is by checking the URL when modifying the attribute via Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes

Comment: Even if this might work. you shouldn't do raw queries and you shouldn't call `load` inside a loop. Big performance killer.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't go the route of ever loading within the query, just didn't know which changes he was interested in making. Raw SQL across the whole catalog would be a great performance boost over using Magento's orm assuming his catalog is over 4000 products? Or am I mistaken.

Comment: Sure..direct query is fasted but the fact that you are loading all the fresh arrivals cancels the boost from the direct query. It makes it even worse.

Comment: Understood. I've edited the answer to indicate how to make these changes via SQL. Ty Marius.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('fresh_arrival', array('eq'=>1));

foreach($collection as $product){
    //do something
}
```